# SSH Egress Settings for Google Cloud Functions to connect to Egnyte SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp, gcp, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to use Google Cloud Function to connect with an Egnyte SFTP server and transfer files to Google Cloud Storage.

Currently, I have a Python script that uses Paramiko to connect and that script has been tested locally and remotely using Colab.  I've also been able to confirm the host and port connection in a variety of other ways.

But within GCF I'm running into a timeout issue.

From the research that I've done, it looks like that it could be a firewall setting or a VPC network setting within the Egress settings.

I've tried updating the firewalls rule for the default environment to allow for egress on port 22, but that didn't seem to do anything.

There's a way to add a custom VPC Connector or 'add New VPC Connector' but I'm unfamiliar with those configurations.

Any thoughts here on how to proceed?

TIA